# Texts in Ads is not so readable in Dark Mode

Tags: bug, design, advertising, dark-mode

I saw the below Ad today, apparently the benefits in the ads is not readable. Is this bug is happening because of I am using Dark mode or the Ad is just like that ?

I think this is not providing a good user experience, is there any way we can report these type of Ads to the community to make it better.

[image]

Comment: Must be related to dark mode, this happened to me too and the text became legible when I switched to light mode.